# how to install highcharts with bower

Tags: ember.js, highcharts, bower, bower-install

I am starting a new Ember-CLI project.  And I want to install HighCharts with bower.

How do I do this?

I have read two posts about this.

The first one tells me to:`bower install highcharts.com`

Unfortunately the install hangs and eventually crashes

The second post tells me to: `bower install https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts-release`

But this only seems to install a `bower.json` and an `index` file... but no js files?

In this specific case, can I just manually place the highcharts.js into my own vendor folder... update brocfile and just forget bower for now?  Is there any downside to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found that the unzipping of highcharts.com does take way longer than any other repo, but it should succeed eventually. There is also `highcharts-release`, which you mentioned. You should be able to just enter the following,

`bower install highcharts-release`

Once that installs you should have the files `highcharts.js` and `highcharts.src.js` at your disposal.

Try using the keyword -- `highcharts-release` instead of the full path.

highcharts-release contains way fewer files, which should resolve your issue.

If you use your own vendor folder, it will be harder to update to newer releases in the future, I would not recommend it unless using bower is really impossible, which is somewhat doubtful.

Comment: notice above i attempted to use `highcharts-release`, but it only installed a `.json` file and an `index` file for some reason?

Comment: Try just using the keyword and not the full path. I just tried it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to update the bower.json and install it via CLI from the project directory.

```
bower install
```

[image]